# PHP - Using self vs $this to access protected members from within a class?

Tags: php, this, self, protected

Say I have a protected method in PHP, as shown below:

```
class Test {

    protected function hello($x) {
        echo "hello " . $x . "<br>";
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $i = 2;
        self::hello($i);
        $this::hello($i);
    }
}

$test = new Test();
```

The output is `hello 2` printed twice. So calling the protected method `hello` works via both self and $this. Which is the correct approach? My personal answer is self, since $this refers to the current object, and any object of this class shouldn't have access to its protected method. Am I right or wrong?

**Edit**: This question isn't a duplicate. The other question talks only about accessing static members members through self and $this. I am interested in protected members specifically.

Comment: @puelo That question and its answers talk only about accessing static members through self and $this. Not protected members.

Comment: Use $this->hello(). $this refers to the instance of Test. You would only want to use self:: when working with polymorphism

Comment: Protected function is available to call in a class consructor.

Comment: @Aknosis But aren't protected methods not accessible through instances of the class? That's why I think using $this doesn't make sense. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lebowski All methods/fields are accessible to the class itself (private, protected, or public). They are not accessible outside of the class. (e.g. you can't do $test->hello(), but from inside the class you can do $this->hello();